# Centering a multiple line part tite in the toc

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, parts

I'm stumped. How can I centre a multiple line part title in the toc?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright]{book}  

\usepackage{tocloft}% toc spacing and ragged right (below)  
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}  
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large}  
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}  

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents  
\chapter{Chapter 1}  
\chapter{Chapter 2}  
\part{A moderately long part title}  
\chapter{Chapter 3}  
\chapter{Chapter 4}  
\chapter{Chapter 5}  
\part{A Very very very long part title which runs over multiple lines in the table of contents}  
\chapter{Chapter 6}  
\chapter{Chapter 7}  
\chapter{Chapter 8}  

\end{document}
```

Ideally, I would like the toc to be laid out as:

```
                       Contents
```

1. Introduction  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1

   ```
                       Part I
            A moderately long part title
   ```
2. Chapter 2 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 10
3. Chapter 3 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 20
4. Chapter 4 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 30

   ```
                      Part II
    A Very very very long part title which runs 
    over multiple lines in the table of contents
   ```
5. Chapter 5 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 40
6. Chapter 6 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 50

I'm sorry if this has been asked before but I've spent hours trying to hack a solution together to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  This is an interesting question and I am sure, there is some expert, which will answer your question soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I my point of view, using a patch of `\@part` is easier than using `tocloft` commands here.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright]{book}  

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{tocloft}% toc spacing and ragged right (below)  



%\cftpagenumbersoff{part}  
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@part}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
}{%
  % Rather use an `\addcontentsline` to get rid off the restrictions of `\contentsline` etc. 
  \addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\Large \mdseries\protect\centering\partname\ \thepart\par\large\protect\centering#1\par\endgroup}
}{}{}


\makeatother

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large}  
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}  


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents  
\chapter{Chapter 1}  
\chapter{Chapter 2}  
\part{A moderately long part title}  
\chapter{Chapter 3}  
\chapter{Chapter 4}  
\chapter{Chapter 5}  
\part{A Very very very long part title which runs over multiple lines in the table of contents}  
\chapter{Chapter 6}  
\chapter{Chapter 7}  
\chapter{Chapter 8}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

**A different setup with a `\parbox`**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright]{book}  




\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{tocloft}% toc spacing and ragged right (below)  


\DeclareRobustCommand{\wrapmytitles}[1]{%
  \leavevmode

  \centering
  \parbox{0.7\linewidth}{\centering #1}%

}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@part}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\Large \mdseries\protect\centering\partname\ \thepart\par\large\wrapmytitles{#1}\endgroup}
}{}{}


\makeatother

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large}  
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}  


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents  
\chapter{Chapter 1}  
\chapter{Chapter 2}  
\part{A moderately long part title}  
\chapter{Chapter 3}  
\chapter{Chapter 4}  
\chapter{Chapter 5}  
\part{A Very very very long part title which runs over multiple lines in the table of contents}  
\chapter{Chapter 6}  
\chapter{Chapter 7}  
\chapter{Chapter 8}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice.  for the first example, you could easily limit the width of the entry by setting `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` to some convenient value, say 1.5cm, within the redefinition.  this will disappear (along with font changes) when processing of the entry is finished.

Comment: This solution is very elegant. However, I've found that it doesn't play nicely with the packages "hyperref " and "doi". Have you got any idea why that might be?

Comment: Just to answer my own question. Hyperref redefines \addcontentsline so the redefinition of part needs to go before hyperref is loaded.

Comment: @user1844282: Yes I know. Your original question did not mention anything about `hyperref` so I did not include that

Comment: It wasn't a criticism. Your solution is perfect and yes the original question never mentioned hyperref. It's just something which gave me trouble when moving from the mwe to my actual document, so I wanted to leave directions for others of my skill level to whom the order in which things should be placed in the preamble is not obvious.